# Periodic web scraping to scrape new information on the website since the last time it ran

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping this website: https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs. I have the code to scrape the website and store the required information in the local database. The information that I need to scrape is:

1. The name of the company that is hiring.
2. The location of the company.
3. The position that the ad is for.

My question is: how can improve my script to perform the following tasks?

1. Scrape the website periodically.
2. Scraper should only scrape new information on the website since the last 
   time it ran.

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs"
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

table = content.find("table", attrs={"class":"itemlist"})

array = []
for elem in table.findAll("a", attrs={"class":"storylink"}):
    array.append(elem.text)

try:
    # open the database connection
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='mypassword',
                                  host='localhost', database='scraping')
    insert_sql = ('INSERT INTO `jobs` (`listing`) VALUES (%s)')

    # get listing data
    listing_data = array

    # loop through all listings executing INSERT for each with the cursor
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    for listing in listing_data:
        print('Storing data for %s' % (listing))
        cursor.execute(insert_sql, (listing,))

    # commit the new records
    cnx.commit()

    # close the cursor and connection
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print('Something is wrong with your username or password')
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print('Database does not exist')
    else:
        print(err)

else:
    cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You could set up a cron job to make this script run periodically.

2) There is also something you missed in the DOM:

```
<tr class="athing" id="20190856">
      <td align="right" valign="top" class="title"><span class="rank"></span></td>      <td></td><td class="title">...
```

Each job posting has a unique ID (according to the HN API doc: https://github.com/HackerNews/API ), so just scrape this ID and make sure you don't already have it in your database.

You could also just consume the API instead of scraping the HTML!

Comment: i got the first part working, i am on windows so i used task scheduler. About the second part tell me if i am on track.
I need to first get all the id's already in my database(if id's exists) than compare the id's of scraped items and if the id is new than insert it into the database otherwise neglect it. right?

Comment: Yes this is what you should do! You could also use an ORM like SqlAlchemy to make things easier and not having to write the SQL queries yourself.

Comment: Well this solution seems alright for this small scale project. What do you suggest if it was a large scale project where i had to scrape a few thousand items at a time. Soon my database will have millions of records with which i have to compare the id. Isn't there any way to only scrape the new information on the web without comparing the item id's with database item id's?

Comment: You could make this ID a primary key and let your database check if it already exists. Primary keys are by nature indexed so it doesn't matter if you have few or millions of records !

Comment: That make sense.